# using windows 8, message says problem with this drive

Tags: ipod

recently bought a new computer with windows 8. Installed ITunes and all my music is on the computer. When I plug in my Ipod classic to synch new music added I get the following message: There's a problem with this drive. Scan the drive now and fix it. I am a 65 year old that doesn't know what they want me to do. If I restore it to factory it will wipe all the music off of it right? Anything else I can do? I don't understand how to scan the drive and fix it. Thanks. Carol

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs is most frequently because you didn't safe eject the device (in this case, your iPod) from your computer. The message will continue to appear every time you plug in your iPod until you click it (the message), and then click "Scan and fix". Windows will run a program called CHKDSK in the background, which will fix any problems with your iPod's storage. It's very unlikely that you will lose data when you do this as CHKDSK is specifically designed to find and fix problems with data.

To prevent the message occurring in future, you should safely eject the device. This basically lets the device know that you want to unplug it, so it can finish communicating with Windows and save any data to its storage. If you just pull the cable out without first telling the iPod what you're about to do, it might still be half-way through transferring some data. To safely eject the iPod, refer to this Apple Support article: http://support.apple.com/en-is/HT201646

**Note:** Even if you weren't actually transferring data when you unplugged it, if you don't safely eject it, the device will know it wasn't correctly unmounted from the computer before being removed and will tell Windows next time you plug it in, causing that message to pop up. Also, unlike what angus batkin said, it's definitely not a bug in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting this message with my brand new iPod classic too. I scanned it like it asked a couple times and nothing changes.
I suspect its just a bug with windows 8, so as long as the iPod functions with iTunes then just ignore the message. If there is actually a problem with the device though, just click on the message box that pops up with the warning and it should bring up a small window to run a scan on the iPod.

Answer (score 0):

I've never disconnected my iPod without safely ejecting it. I got the "There's a problem" message and trouble syncing it. I tried a lot of different solutions that I found on the web. Here's what worked for me: Uninstalling and reinstalling iTunes. It sure beats having Windows try to scan and repair an Apple device (which I tried, but it didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the blue message that says  'problem with this drive'.
It should then come up and say 'scan and fix recommended' or something like ignore or continue below it. Click ignore/continue and the ipod should just connect to itunes like normal.

Answer (score 0):

Either close the error popup box or click on "Continue without scanning". You can ignore the error. You do NOT need to factory restore your iPod.

The reason is probably that you didn't safely eject your iPod the last time you disconnected it from your computer. Safely eject is basically that your computer stops using the memory in the iPod. Before you disconnect it.

If you want to know how to eject your iPod safely, this article may help you: [Link to article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/safely-remove-devices-from-your-computer).